# Javascript output to textbox based on another textbox value

Tags: javascript, forms, search, textbox, output

I am trying to create a javascript form where there is an input which outputs words into a textbox, then based on the presence of some of the words (not exact phrases) within that box there is a second output in another textbox.
I have a feeling it probably requires a .search command and something to do with regexp but I am struggling to work out how to implement it.

The below is not the final implementation, but an example form of the same idea:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate(){

var input = document.input.value;
var output1 = document.output1.value;

if (input = 1){
output1 = "x type 1";
}

else if (input = 2){
output1 = "y type 1";
}

else if (input = 3){
output1 = "y type 2";
}

if (output1.search("type 1"){
document.output2.value = "z";
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Input<input type="textbox" name="input"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate" /><br>
<textarea rows="2" name="output1" ></textarea>
<textarea rows="2" name="output2" ></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to get the function to search the textbox "output1" and if it contains the words "type 1" in this example, then it outputs something into textbox "output2". I don't think the output1 as a result of the input is working in this example (not sure why) but I'm mainly trying to figure out output2 based on words contained in box output1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `input = 1` will always be true. You need to use the `==` or `===` operator in `if` statements, not the assignment operator. You also have a syntax error missing a `)`. First step to find errors indent your code properly and use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). Example:

```
var input = 'here i have some words';
var out;

if (input.indexOf('some') !== -1) {
    out = 'I have some in input!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has several error mark those error following:

1. `document.input.value` instead of `document.getElementById("input").value`
2. `var output1 = document.output1.value;` instead of `var output1;`
3. in all if method change `input = 1` instead of `input == 1`
4. change `document.output2.value` instead of `document.getElementsByName("output2").value`
5. add `document.getElementsByName("output1").value=output1;` for set value
6. add `id` in `html` element

**i used to get element from id so added in html element if you use other way learn javaScript**

i think you should need to [learn JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) well.

reformatting your code you wriiten systex lots of error i fixed and following full code:

```js
function calculate(){
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var output1;
if (input == 1){
output1 = "x type 1";
}


else if (input == 2){
output1 = "y type 1";
}

else if (input == 3){
output1 = "y type 2";
}

if (output1.search("type 1")){
document.getElementById("output2").value="z";
}
document.getElementById("output1").value=output1;

}
```

```html
<form>
Input<input type="textbox" name="input" id="input"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate" /><br>
<textarea rows="2" name="output1" id="output1"></textarea>
<textarea rows="2" name="output2" id="output2"></textarea>
</form>
```

let me know if it's help or any question.